# GET request NodeMCU(ESP8266) 301 Error

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, esp8266, nodemcu

Few days ago i'm post question about nodeMcu POST request, can't find any solution i'm try next on:

```
conn=net.createConnection(net.TCP, 0)
conn:on("receive", function(conn, payload) print(payload) end )
conn:on("connection", function(c)
conn:send("GET /wifi?temp=24&hum=12&alert HTTP/1.1\r\n"
.."Host: www.weatherman.bl.ee\r\n"
.."Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
.."Connection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: */*\r\n\r\n")
end)
conn:connect(80, "www.weatherman.bl.ee")
```

But this request respond me with 301 error

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Date: Mon, 02 Nov 2015 20:03:50 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.weatherman.bl.ee/wifi/?temp=24&hum=12&alert
Content-Length: 270
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100 
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Any ideas? May be problem with header's?
Postman execute request fine

Comment: I tried the same code and it returns with `Data saved succesfully` for me. There is perhaps something else causing the 301 redirect?

Comment: same code on node mcu firmware? if yes tell me your version number, please

Comment: Not on nodemcu; but the same lua code (and the same header in curl) using luasocket library.

Comment: You should accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server probably enforces a `/` at the end of the request URL path.

If you use the URL with an extra `/`, that the redirect response tries to redirect you, you shouldn't get a 301 response back.

```
/wifi/?temp=24&hum=12&alert
     ↑
     └ extra slash
```

Answer (score 1):

Status 301 is not an error, everything from 200-399 is considered success.  In the case of 301 there will be a location header, that you use to build the redirected URL.  301 is returned by the server in response to a given URL, the only thing you can do (besides using location to follow it) on the client is use a different URL.